# Running npm in concourse pipeline

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, concourse

How can I add as part of my pipeline that it needs to grab the git repository , run npm install and npm build and then push to cloud foundry?.

So far i am able to make it so that it grabs the repository and pushes to cloud foundry. But not completely sure on how to make it so that it builds the npm tasks. I am using a BOSH director to handle all the concourse stuff.

Any direction or ideas will be very appreciated. I am following this tutorial here and based my pipeline on this:
(where and how would i go about adding building npm tasks?)

```
---
resources:
- name: resource-web-app
  type: git
  source:
    uri: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/simple-go-web-app.git

- name: resource-deploy-web-app
  type: cf
  source:
    api: {{cf-api}}
    username: {{cf-username}}
    password: {{cf-password}}
    organization: {{cf-organization}}
    space: {{cf-space}}
    skip_cert_check: true

jobs:
- name: job-deploy-app
  serial: true
  plan:
  - {get: resource-web-app, trigger: true}
  - put: resource-deploy-web-app
    params:
      manifest: resource-web-app/manifest.yml
      path: resource-web-app
```

https://github.com/starkandwayne/concourse-tutorial/tree/master/15_deploy_cloudfoundry_app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a [task](https://concourse.ci/running-tasks.html) that runs a script that runs `npm install` and `npm build` prior to pushing to cloud foundry.

It is also important to note that in the below script concourse will look for the bits to push to cf in the directory `resource-deploy-web-app`, so make sure to put everything you want to push there in your script.

So your new job configuration is going to look something like:

```
jobs:
- name: job-deploy-app
  serial: true
  plan:
  - {get: resource-web-app, trigger: true}
  - task: build-npm
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source:
          repository: node

      inputs:
        - name: resource-web-app

      run:
        path: resource-web-app/scripts/script-that-does-npm-stuff.sh

      outputs:
        - name: resource-deploy-web-app

 - put: resource-deploy-web-app
   params:
      manifest: resource-web-app/manifest.yml
      path: resource-web-app
```

Comment: Awesome man!, thanks a lot for this, one last question. Probably unrelated. With this pipeline, anytime i check in into my master.. it will just push to cloud foundry correct? - because of the trigger?

Comment: Yeah, any time you push to master the job `job-deploy-app` will run

Comment: Hi Josh, for some readon i get a "mapping values are not allowed in this context" for the line where the - put is.

Comment: I had params moved a bit to the right.. so i aligned it how you have it and i get a different error though: build-npm does not specify any task configuration

Comment: update: I manage to make it run by adding a config: right below the task but now it says resource-web-app/scripts/scripts/npmbuild.sh : permission denied. I added user: root below the path per the documentation but it did not make a difference

Comment: make sure to run chmod +x on the script before pushing it to github, github picks up your file permissions

Comment: Also sorry about any errors in the yaml I showed you... glad you got it work